# How can I transfer my Ethereum from Etherdelta to Coinbase?

Tags: etherdelta

Does anyone know how to transfer ETH from Etherdelta to Coinbase? Thanks Bob

Answer (score 1):

It should be a simple address-to-address transaction.

- Step 1: find out the destination address (your Coinbase address). [Coinbase provides documentation for how to do this](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2340440-how-do-i-receive-digital-currency-).
- Step 2: Log-in to EtherDelta
- Step 3: Withdraw the funds from your EtherDelta wallet to you wallet (most likely MetaMask in your browser). EtherDelta provides documentation [for withdrawing, transferring etc.](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherDelta/comments/6hrmsl/how_to_deposit_withdraw_and_transfer/).
- Step 4: Send the funds from your wallet address to the Coinbase wallet address identified from *Step 1*.